# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`S.SID`'

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am using **Java** language.I have below query in my code :

```
public static String GET_E_BCHGS = "SELECT BCL.* "
+"FROM (SELECT * " 
      +"FROM (SELECT (SELECT BILLABLE_CHG_ID " 
                    +"FROM BC " 
                    +"WHERE BC.BILLABLE_CHG_STAT = 10 "
                    +"AND BC.FEED_SOURCE_FLG = 'TFM' " 
                    +" AND BC.SA_ID = S.SA_ID AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 " 
                                                        +"FROM BCC " 
                                                        +"WHERE BCC.BILLABLE_CHG_ID = BC.BILLABLE_CHG_ID " 
                                                        +"AND BCC.CHAR_TYPE_CD = 'AGG_CRTA' " 
                                                        +"AND BCC.ADHOC_CHAR_VAL = S.SID) " 
                                                        +"OR "
                                                        +"(BC.PRICEITEM_CD = S.FIN_PRICEITEM_CD " 
                                                        +"AND BC.TOU_CD =S.TOU_CD " 
                                                        +"AND BC.START_DT =S.BCHG_START_DT " 
                                                        +"AND BC.END_DT =S.BCHG_END_DT " 
                                                        +"AND BC.PRICE_ASGN_ID= S.PRICE_ASGN_ID " 
                                                        +"AND BC.PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID = S.PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID " 
                                                        +"AND BC.AGG_PARM_GRP_ID = S.AGG_PARM_GRP_ID) "
                                                +") AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 " 
                                                                  +"FROM C, BS " 
                                                                  +"WHERE BS.bseg_id = C.bseg_id " 
                                                                  +"AND C.billable_chg_id = BC.BILLABLE_CHG_ID " 
                                                                  +"AND BS.bseg_stat_flg not in (10,60))) " 
              +"AS BILLABLE_CHG_ID " 
              +"FROM S " 
              +"WHERE SID >= '2100000000063000004222017020100018243020717805750011' " 
             +"AND SID <= null " 
             +"AND " 
              +"STATUS = ' ' " 
              +"AND TXN_RATING_CRITERIA ='RITA') " 
        +"WHERE BILLABLE_CHG_ID <> ' ' " 
        +"GROUP BY BILLABLE_CHG_ID) F, BCL " 
+"WHERE F.BILLABLE_CHG_ID = BCL.BILLABLE_CHG_ID " 
+"ORDER BY BCL.BILLABLE_CHG_ID, LINE_SEQ";
```

I am trying to use same in Spark SQL, below is the code for same :

```
Dataset<Row> bc = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "B_CHG").load();
    bc.createOrReplaceTempView("BC");
    Dataset<Row> bcc = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "B_CHG_CHAR").load();
    bcc.createOrReplaceTempView("BCC");
    Dataset<Row> c = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "B_CALC").load();
    c.createOrReplaceTempView("C");
    Dataset<Row> bs = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "BSEG").load();
    bs.createOrReplaceTempView("BS");
    Dataset<Row> s = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "TXN_DTL_P_SUMMARY").load();
    s.createOrReplaceTempView("S");
    Dataset<Row> bcl = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", "B_CHG_L").load();
    bcl.createOrReplaceTempView("BCL");
    
    Dataset<Row> existingBchgsDS = sparkSession.sql(SQQueries.GET_E_BCHGS);
    existingBchgsDS.show();
```

while running this code i am getting below mentioned error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`S.SID`' given input columns: [bcc.CHAR_VAL_FK4, bcc.CHAR_VAL_FK2, bcc.CHAR_VAL_FK5, bcc.BILLABLE_CHG_ID, bcc.ADHOC_CHAR_VAL, bcc.CHAR_VAL_FK3, bcc.CHAR_TYPE_CD, bcc.SRCH_CHAR_VAL, bcc.CHAR_VAL_FK1, bcc.CHAR_VAL, bcc.VERSION, bcc.EFFDT]; line 1 pos 297;
'Sort ['BCL.BILLABLE_CHG_ID ASC NULLS FIRST, 'LINE_SEQ ASC NULLS FIRST], true.........

//more lines of error
```

I want to understand :

1. what is wrong with this query? Same query runs correctly on sql developer.
2. Are such queries supported by Spark SQL?

   or
3. is there any other way to write same?

Spark Version : 2.3.0

Comment: Spark SQL only support ANSI SQL (SQL-92?) and HiveQL.

Comment: @philantrovert okay so is there any way to run above query using spark sql? i am using oracle db.

Comment: Why don't you execute the entire query over JDBC instead of caching temporary tables in Spark?

Comment: @philantrovert so are you suggesting to use JDBC in spark? because my understanding is it will reduce the performance. by using JDBC we wont get any benefit of spark functionality... is that true?

Comment: That depends on how your table is structured. You can specify various JDBC properties to enhance performace but, in general, queries over jDBC will be less performant than queries over Hive via Spark.

Comment: @philantrovert yes, actually i am trying to convert existing batch code in java with an oracle's internal framework to java code in spark framework, now in existing code JDBC is used, and if I use same here as well then no advantage of spark right? so apart from JDBC there are no other alternatives? without using Hive I mean.

Comment: IS the issue resolved ? @Raj   I am also facing similar issue when i write my streamed data to hive table (insert into operation)

Comment: @BigD yes but my issue was related to format of SQL Query so I changed the format and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think what you are doing is correct you can write `sparkSession.sql()` as the error states i think its unable to figure out the `column SID` in `Dataset S` after applying all the other conditions, i think its better for us to understand if you can post the schema of the Datasets as well.
2. Yes there are supported but i recommend to use the filter and select and other on the data set so that you will have much better control over the code.
   The main change is the ease of coding and debugging. With spark.sql, you won't have any infos at compile time about errors or type mistakes...And using .filter, .select is much easier to indent, to read, etc... and it has the same performance.

Comment: I have tried to write this query using filter and select but it is getting very much complex., can you give me an example how to write such complex queries using select and filter?

Comment: Also query runs correctly on sql developer , then what is the issue here?

Comment: So you copied the exact words of my answer but still unaccepted it... that's quite unfortunate behaviour right there :'( Have a good day @Sundeep Pidugu Mouahahha